# Deleting numpy array elements from a 3d numpy array with given array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
arr = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])
```

and an array of indices, `ind = array([0, 1, 1])`

What I would like to do is for the `i`th row in `arr`, delete the `ind[i]`th row in `arr[i]` using only numpy.delete.

So in essence a more pythonic way to do this:

```
x, y, z = arr.shape
new_arr = np.empty((x, y - 1, z))
for i, j in enumerate(ind):
    new_arr[i] = np.delete(arr[i], j, 0)

arr = new_arr.astype(int)
```

So the output here would be:

```
array([[[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: You probably need to create a new, smaller array, and then copy what you need. There is no way to delete what you need in a loop because the array is not fixed-sized.

Comment: So, the code I posted is the only way to do achieve this?
Ah, rip, I was hoping numpy had some way to do this which was more optimized.

Comment: The code you posted delete the *rows* of `a[i]`'s, not the *columns*. Which exactly do you want to delete, rows or columns?

Comment: @QuangHoang, the array is 3d, so the names 'rows' and 'columns' are ambiguous.  Here the OP is thinking of the 0 and 1 axes, you seem think of them as 1 and 2.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, `np.delete` makes a new array too.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant rows.

Comment: @hpaulj I know. My point is that due to the different indices to remove, you need a loop and store the partial in a new, shorter array, as OP did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working solution:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8]],

                [[9, 10, 11],
                 [12, 13, 14],
                 [15, 16, 17]],

                [[18, 19, 20],
                 [21, 22, 23],
                 [24, 25, 26]]])


a0, a1, a2 = arr.shape
indices = np.array([0, 1, 1])

mask = np.ones_like(arr, dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(a0), indices, :] = False

result = arr[mask].reshape((a0, -1, a2))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [24 25 26]]]
```

Comment: There's nothing hacky about that.  `np.delete` does that sort of boolean masking, but doesn't generalize it to the 2d case as you did.  I was slowly working toward this sort of solution.  The last reshape can be `reshape(a0, -1, a2)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your comments, updated the answer!